# Why it is taking the same time?

Tags: shell, time, makefile

I am running the following inside the makefile:-

```
@START=$(shell date +%s) && \
echo $${START} &&\
sleep 10s && \
END=$(shell date +%s) && \
echo "$${END} $${START}" &&\
DIFF_SUB=$$(($$END - $$START)) && \
echo IT TOOK $${DIFF_SUB} SECONDS
```

and it outputs to the following:-

> 1309950228 
>   1309950228 1309950228 
>   IT TOOK 0 SECONDS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting the same result for each `$(shell date +%s)` is that each is being executed and substituted at the same time - that is when `make` is running the command.

After `make` does its substitutions, this is the command the shell sees:

```
@START=1309950228 && \
echo ${START} &&\
sleep 10s && \
END=1309950228 && \
echo "${END} ${START}" &&\
DIFF_SUB=$(($END - $START)) && \
echo IT TOOK ${DIFF_SUB} SECONDS
```

If you want the `date` command to be run twice with a 10 second time difference between them, you will need the shell to perform the command substitution, not `make`:

```
@START=$$(date +%s) && \
echo $${START} &&\
sleep 10s && \
END=$$(date +%s) && \
echo "$${END} $${START}" &&\
DIFF_SUB=$$(($$END - $$START)) && \
echo IT TOOK $${DIFF_SUB} SECONDS
```

Note the double `$$` and the removal of the `shell` `make` command.

Answer (score 0):

`make` expands all variable and function references in the body of a rule before executing any of it.  Since you're using `$(shell)` to run the `date` command, that actually means that both calls to `date` are getting run before `sleep`.

Keep in mind that the body of a rule is *already* executed using the shell, so generally it's redundant to use `$(shell)` in that context anyway -- just let the shell do it's thing, instead of trying to get `make` to do part of it.  See camh's answer for an example of how to do this.

You can read more about the relationship between `make` and the shell here:  [Shell commands in GNU make](http://blog.melski.net/2010/11/15/shell-commands-in-gnu-make/).